# Can hibernate call return a XML data?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm

I would like to know if we call a Java class annotated with hibernate classes. Can we get the data from the table in a XML format?

browser give data for id =1 --> Servlet --> hibernate class (with some magic xml functionality) --> returns the data in XML format(Can this really happen?)

Thanks,
Sana.

Comment: http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/mapping/
  1st para and 6th line
  You can retrieve database table data as an XML document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any particular experience with this feature but Hibernate allows you to work with persistent XML that you can persist to or read from the database. See [Chapter 18. XML Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html). I'm not sure it's still actively developed though, and it doesn't support annotations AFAIK.

As an alternative, you could use Hibernate/JPA + JAXB (in which case, I'd suggest to check [HyperJAXB](https://hyperjaxb.dev.java.net/)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do this directly with Hibernate, but you could use a 3rd party library like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to transform the object you have stored your results in to XML.